# Bootstrap toggle icon not showing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am learning bootstrap and trying to make a navbar but the navbar toggler hamburger icon doesn't show up. A portion of the code I currently have is below. Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Personal Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bootstrap `.navbar-toggler-icon` styling will depend on what theme your navbar would be. For example try using `navbar-light` on your `navbar` this will produce the hamburger with `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)` stroke.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Personal Website</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#uniqueIdentifier">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      <div id="uniqueIdentifier" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```